# how to pass Json data in Android Adapter

Tags: android, json

Hello I am trying to pass Json Data from Adapter to another Activity

```
 playb = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.playbtn);
   playb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          //  Song newitem = getItem(position);
           //long itemId = getItemId(position);
            app = (myapplication) getContext().getApplicationContext();
            app.setSong(item);
           Intent intent1 = new Intent(getContext(), SongDetailedActivity.class);

             intent1.putExtra("SongID", item.toString());
           getContext().startActivity(intent1);
       }
   });
```

and my activity

```
 Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
        hello = i.getIntExtra("SongID", 5);
        Song event = app.getSongID(hello);
        event.setSongID(hello);
```

Comment: You are passing String in "SongId" and getting back it in Int. you might need to correct that thing before I go for question

Comment: Very good you are passing it (although fetching is wrong but anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity,

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("SongID")){
  String json = bundle.getString("SongID");
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
  //parse json from here...don't forget to handle JSONException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can whether pass an integer value and catch it using `i.getIntExtra()`
or pass a String and catch using `i.getStringExtra()`
You can't put a string in intent and get it as integer, should has the same type.

Comment: Thank you very much, that just did it